# Using a Azure Service Principal in a module leads to provider error

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I am setting up an infrastructure on Azure and my tool of choice for the code is Terraform.

To have a nice maintainable code, I decided to use modules. My current structure looks like this:

```
├── development/
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── vars.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│  
├── modules/
│   ├── provider
│   └── resource-group
│   └── eventhub
```

So, I even put out the provider code into a module. My code looks something like this:

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {}
}

module "provider" {
  tenant_id       = "${var.tenant_id}"
  client_id       = "${var.client_id}"
  client_secret   = "${var.client_secret}"
  subscription_id = "${var.subscription_id}"
  source          = "../modules/provider"
}

module "resource-group" {
  source = "../modules/resource-group"
}

module "iothub" {
  name     = "${module.resource-group.name}"
  location = "${module.resource-group.location}"
  source   = "../modules/iothub"
}
```

But when I run `terraform apply` I get the error message of `* provider.azurerm: Error validating provider: No valid (unexpired) Azure CLI Auth Tokens found. Please run`az login`.`

I already fixed this by moving the code from the provider module into the `main.tf` file for my development environment. But I am curious why this is happening in the first place. Is the provider resource required in the root module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to pass a provider configuration upwards so while it is possible to define providers in a module you can't then pass that provider configuration to a parent (including the root) or sibling module.

Terraform's own [module documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html#providers-within-modules) that you should define all providers at the root level.

I personally achieve this by defining a single provider file per configuration and then symlink this around to every appropriate location meaning I can change configuration in an easier way but there are other approaches as well.

Note that you may occasionally have a good reason for defining a provider directly in a resource. I personally define the [`postgresql` provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/postgresql/index.html) configuration in my Postgresql RDS module that creates an [AWS RDS Postgresql instance](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html) and then configures users and databases using the PostgreSQL provider, connecting to the dynamic endpoint exposed by the RDS instance on creation.